# What details or clarification should I provide when asking about the differences between using text-davinci-003 with the Azure API vs with OpenAI API?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

My question [Is there any differences between using text-davinci-003 with the Azure API vs. with the OpenAI API?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/118127/843) was closed as needing details or clarity. What details or clarification should I provide? Close voters left no comments.

Same question posted on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/12gb9be/d_chat_gpt_azure_ai_vs_openai/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=android_app&utm_name=androidcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button).